# div set to relative but cant flush to the top of the page

Tags: html, css

so im very confused about how div's connect, the parent has to be relative (or fixed????) and the child has to be absolute but i want a top menu the same as this site which means i need to make the top menu div with a property of 
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
but then this means i cant flush a div underneath to the top menu if thats set to relative

```css
html, body {
 background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
/* Div Body Start */
#container {
 width: 100%
 height: 100%;

}

#topmenu {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.6; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */
  
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
#topmenu:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
}

#banner {
    position: absolute;
 clear: both;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top: 5px solid black;
 
 background: #00015E; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* Standard syntax */
 

 height: 15%
 
}
/* Div Body End */
/* Top Menu Script Start */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visable;
    background-color: black;
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
   margin:auto;
   display:block;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: lime;
}
/* Top Menu Script End */
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="topmenu">
<ul>

  <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Education</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Hobbys</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="index.html"><img class="topimages" src="images/icons/icon-home1.png" width="35" height="35"></a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- End topmenu -->
<div id="banner">


</div>
</div><!-- End container -->
```

I really didnt want to use the
top: 55px;
from the screen as it makes it go all weird later on when scrolling down a page
Ive searched this situation but i cant find any answers, might not be looking well enough.... thanks guys!

Comment: what do you mean by "flush"? You don't need to absolutely position a div for it to be at the top of the page, it will do that by default.

Comment: When I get rid of the position it will have like a padding away from the very top of the screen, I'm trying to get a top screen menu like this website (stock overflow) then have a banner or any div connect to the top menu. Flush as in 0px's away from each other? Divs connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing padding and margin from the body, and positioning the submenu the normal way, works fine for me in FF, Chrome, IE:

```css
html, body {
 background-color: #E8E8E8;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
/* Div Body Start */
#container {
 width: 100%
 height: 100%;

}

#topmenu {
 opacity: 0.6; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* internet explorer */

    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
#topmenu:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
}

#banner {
    position: absolute;
 clear: both;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 750px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-top: 5px solid black;
 
 background: #00015E; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#00015E, #3943FF); /* Standard syntax */
 

 height: 15%
 
}
/* Div Body End */
/* Top Menu Script Start */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visable;
    background-color: black;
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 5px solid black;
   margin:auto;
   display:block;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: lime;
}
/* Top Menu Script End */
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="topmenu">
<ul>

  <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Education</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Hobbys</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a href="index.html"><img class="topimages" src="images/icons/icon-home1.png" width="35" height="35"></a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- End topmenu -->
<div id="banner">


</div>
</div><!-- End container -->
```

Comment: This works perfectly! thank you!!!! though im still confused how you managed this without having a top: 0px; set to the menu?

Comment: It will be at 0px by default.